# Youtube video data retrieval

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

I want to get number of views, duration and also the rating of the particular video in youtube. Is there any way to get the information of the video by passing the video id through URL?

Comment: I usually don't even bother trying to help people that use the site for their own gains without following the rules.

Answer (score 7):

[Youtube Data API.](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api)

Basically, you want to fetch a URL like [`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kpcqAm8BOlE`](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kpcqAm8BOlE)
and look at the resulting XML.

Answer (score 2):

The article [Retrieve Title, Description and Thumbnail of a YouTube Video Using AJAX](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html) describes how you can do this via simple JavaScript and/or AJAX. It uses the YouTube Data API but the the code example here is to-the-point so that you don't get lost searching the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

for the rating, you can parse the video url and find:

```
<button class="master-sprite ratingL ratingL-5.0" title="5.0"></button></div><div id="ratingMessage" ><div id="defaultRatingMessage"><span class="smallText">719 ratings
```

notice 5.0 and 719 here. 5.0 is the rating and 719 is the number of votes.