# How to integrate YouTube API into my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I want to integrate the YouTube API into my app, how can I do this?

P.S., 
I'm making an app for a YouTube channel. I tried opening YouTube in a `webview`, but this made everything even worse because the user could see the YouTube controls (search etc.) and that strange message about the "YouTube iPhone app".

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - using YouTube APIs in iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868113/iphone-using-youtube-apis-in-iphone-app)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968097/youtube-video-data-retrieval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do well to read the [YouTube API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html).  If it's like the rest of Google's APIs its probably pretty straightforward.  And for further reading:  [YouTube and iPhone](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)

Comment: Thanks this helped alot, but where can i download that youtube stuff for my app???

Comment: Not sure you understand, DailyDoggy... read the part about "Method 2: Embed the YouTube player in a UIWebView" ..the UIWebView will take care of everything for you.  There's nothing extra to download into your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess b/c I havent done anything like this before but have you tried just passing the YouTube URL for a video to the MPMoviePlayer?

Comment: I tried the MoviePlayer sample from apple. When i press play movie it says: The server is not currently configured. I believe that the API is the only way... Thanks anyways! :)