# You tube API for getting videos from a our account in Objective C

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

In my iphone app i want retrieve videos list from my account in youtube, Is there any API to get this can any one help me out

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get videos by user

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads

the api is documented here,

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html

you would make REST API requests from you iphone app

similar question with additional information

[How to integrate YouTube API into my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440491/how-to-integrate-youtube-api-into-my-iphone-app)